# How do I deploy this code to the eth block

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs-tx

please I need help on this, this code works well on my local machine but doesn’t work on infura main net. I need it done to avoid stress in my business. To automatically transfer my work eth to my personal wallet

```
const TX = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction

let Web3 = require('web3')
let url ='HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545'


let web3 = new  Web3(url)

function intervalFunc(){
  const account1 ='0x2c68F246aBDD28C20c06106E6bf001B79f5dF541'
  const private = Buffer.from('24a684dbbcb9496603c570e1de2289248762110154c69ebe4ffb0ec0f20a1d2d','hex',)
  const privatekey = new Uint8Array((private ))
  console.log(privatekey)
  const account2 = '0xc470268A14016fC3615b5dB4AF5797CF9D8E43dc'


web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1, (error,txCount)=>{
  // build a transation object

  const txObject  ={
    'nonce':web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
    'to': account2,
    'value': web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('2200000', 'gwei')),
    //'gasLimit':web3.utils.toHex(21000),
    'gas': 3141592,      //web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10', 'gwei')),
  }
  console.log(txObject)

  //sign transaction with private key of sender

  const tx = new TX(txObject)
  tx.sign(privatekey)

  //serialize the transaction

const serializedTransaction = tx.serialize()
const raw = '0x' + serializedTransaction.toString('hex')

  //broadcast transaction to the network

  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, (error,txHash) =>{
    console.log(txHash)
  })
})
}
setInterval(intervalFunc, 10000);
```

Comment: I hope that is not ur private key.. if yes then don’t ever use it again and withdraw everytjing form it

Comment: Ur txObject looks weird,What is the number u set on ‚value, and also ‚gas‘ ?

Comment: It is a local machine. How can I deploy this transaction? Do I need to use truffle init?  I am a noob on this .

Comment: You don't need truffle, you have a script that runs each 10000 milliseconds and transfers what in 'value' ether to account2.  In real life your transaction is not directly instantly confirmed (like on your local machine), so you need to wait until the transaction is confirmed and then use a new txCount and send a new transaction. summary: find a blockchain developer to do it, make sure they dont have access to private key OR do it manually it is safer and easier.

Comment: @John When you say "doesn’t work on infura main net" what exactly do you mean? transaction is never created, it is created but fails, it is rejected...